How to remove $0.00 in cell with a formula already in it?
Hello I am wanting to turn any cell that contains "$0.00" into a blank cell. I currently have a formula in the cells that is subtracting the total from two columns.
=MINUS(I9,G9)

Some cells will have $0.00 as I am not putting in any $ amount in the columns being subtracted.
Any help is appreciated thank you!


How about =if(and(not(isBlank(I9)), not(isBlank(G9))), minus(I9,G9), "")

That worked thank you so much!

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

=if(and(not(isBlank(I9)), not(isBlank(G9))), minus(I9,G9), "")
thanks to Matt for his answer!!
